# function in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am trying to self learn the Lisp programming language. I need help defining 
function compute elements in the second list that also appear in the first list.

```css
(defun increasing-sum(list)
 (sort list #'(lambda (sublist1 sublist2)
 (< (apply #'+ sublist1 ) (apply #'+ sublist2)))))
```

Comment: What is the actual question? Also note this usage hint for Stackoverflow: 'Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do.'

Comment: Why does your example returns 17 ? I would say that combining the sets together results in this set `(8 1 (4) 5)` which gives `8 + 1 + 4 + 5 = 18`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's tough to tell from your description, but it sounds like you just need to flatten your lists, compute the intersection, and take the sum of the intersection, and then multiply that by two, since each element in the intersection would have been present in each list.  You can break that down into a **flatten** function, and then use the standard library functions for computing the intersection, sum, and product.

```
(defun flatten (list)
  "Return a list of the non-null leaves of LIST, treated
as a tree of cons cells."
  (cond
   ((null list) list)
   ((atom list) (list list))
   ((append (flatten (first list))
            (flatten (rest list))))))

(flatten '(8 1 (4)))
;=> (8 1 4)

(flatten '(5 (1 (8)) 8 ))
;=> (5 1 8 8)

(defun sum (list1 list2)
  "Flatten LIST1 and LIST2, take their intersection, 
compute the sum over the intersection, and multiply by
two (since each element must have appeared in each list)."
  (* 2 (reduce '+ (intersection (flatten list1)
                                (flatten list2)))))
```

The problem, of course, is that using this algorithm, the intersection for your example would be **(8 1)**, and that will give you **18**, not **17**, as a result:

```
(sum '(8 1 (4)) '(5 (1 (8)) 8))
;=> 18
```

Maybe instead you just wanted to compute the sum of the elements in the second list that also appear in the first list.  In that case, you can use a slightly different algorithm. Just flatten the trees and compute the sum over the elements of the second argument that weren't present in the first.  Note that this really doesn't treat the arguments as *sets*, since *sets* don't have duplicate elements.  This gets the **17** answer that you'd mentioned though.

```
(defun sum2 (list1 list2)
  (let ((set1 (flatten list1)))
    (flet ((in-set-1-p (x)
             (member x set1)))
      (reduce '+ (remove-if-not #'in-set-1-p (flatten list2))))))
```

```
(sum2 '(8 1 (4)) '(5 (1 (8)) 8))
;=> 17
```